# How to make template call work in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this following template which i am not sure correct or not

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="createName">
  <xsl:param name="Type"/>
     <xsl:if test="contains(Type,'NEW')">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('New','Goal')"/>
     </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(Type,'AMD')">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('Amended','Goal')"/>
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling this template here

```
<xsl:element name="PackageName">
                 <xsl:call-template name="createName">
                     <xsl:with-param name="Type" select="s0:PIXField/s0:TransactionID"/>
                 </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:element>
```

s0:PIXField/s0:TransactionID = BPA201605311506452806320060A1AMD

I want to create PackageName element with value 'Amended Goal'.
But for now i am getting empty PackageName. dont know where my code fails.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a parameter, you need to use the `$` prefix. That is to say, do `contains($Type,'NEW')` and not `contains(Type,'NEW')`. The latter is looking for a child element called `Type`, and not the passed in parameter

Try this template. Note that you don't really need to use `xsl:value-of` with `concat` to output the text.

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="createName">
  <xsl:param name="Type"/>
     <xsl:if test="contains($Type,'NEW')">
       <xsl:text>New Goal</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Type,'AMD')">
       <xsl:text>Amended Goal</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Also note, you may not actually need the `match` attribute on the template either, if the template is only ever being called as a named template.

Also consider using `xsl:choose` / `xsl:when` instead of `xsl:if`.

You call this template in exactly the same way as shown in your question

```
<xsl:element name="PackageName">
    <xsl:call-template name="createName">
         <xsl:with-param name="Type" select="s0:PIXField/s0:TransactionID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:element>
```

Nothing changes there at all.

Comment: I need to output text to xsl:element name="PackageName"

Comment: Yes. Your question already contains the code to output the element, so that bit remains the same. Note that I have edited my answer to make it clearer (as also correct a mistake with the template itself).